# How to represent Company return

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-2

I was doing W2 contract work and received my W2s. The company I was contracting for contacted me and claimed they had withheld too much money for city taxes and are returning it to me via fedex in the form of a check tomorrow.

What I am wondering is how do I show this when filing taxes or do I even need to?

Mind you this isn't for last year and the tenure with that company has ended.

Comment: Did they give you an updated W2?

Comment: Not yet. I'll be sure to ask for that thought never crossed my mind thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a prior tax year and the amount isn't all that significant then you might be better off just letting it go.  As long as you can show that you acted in good faith by filing using the W2 given to you *at the time*, it's highly unlikely the government would have much issue with it.

If, as a matter of conscience, it would make you feel better, you can always file an amended return, but I seriously doubt that it would affect your state or federal tax returns, since this was on municipal taxes.  And keep in mind that this is an *over payment*, so you didn't pay less than you should have.  Quite the opposite.